# Run a code after dynamically created element

Tags: jquery

I run the following code from developer tool of my browser:

```
 jQuery(".skiptranslate").contents().filter(function () {
        alert('works again');
        return this.nodeType != 1;
    }).replaceWith("");
```

It works fine. But problem is `.skiptranslate` is generated dynamically by a wordpress plugin. So The above code is not working when I put it into my js file. I know how to write code on dynamically created element. i.e:

```
$(document).on('mouseover mouseout', '.dosomething', function(){
    // what you want to happen when mouseover and mouseout 
    // occurs on elements that match '.dosomething'
});
```

But in my case, event is not like  mouseover,mouseout,click etc. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: (offtopic) you'd better go using `mouseenter mouseleave` instead :D

Comment: You're creating your elements dynamically- and you did not explained when and how << which answers your question.

Comment: Updated!. Please check. Is it enough?

Comment: It's not clear when you need the replacement to happen. Or is it.

Comment: Ask yourself "what action lead to do this one", and you'll find how to rewrite the code above with the dynamic content listener :)